# duplicate entry javax/java/inject.class

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Im having a duplicate entry problem with my android gradle file. I cannot figure out how to fix it. I have searched the issue but cant find anything pertaining to this particular class so i am unsure on what steps to take to get my application to build. My Build.Gradle is shown below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.intellidev.faucetpro"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

}

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/supersonic/android-sdk"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.sharegov:mjson:1.3'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.supersonic.sdk:mediationsdk:6.3.6@jar'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.8'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.8'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.2'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile project(':appgrade')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Check your dependencies and the jar files. You are adding javax/java/inject.class twice.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i know it means this but i have no idea where the duplicate entry is. or how to fix it

Comment: @DreamersOrg Did you find the solution anywhere?